# remove extra characters in all data points in a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, performance, dataframe

I have a dataframe that has field names placed in every field:

```
   index          name      ngram        field     slop  
0  index=1  name=unknown   ngram=00   field=body   slop=0   
1  index=2  name=unknown   ngram=01   field=body   slop=0   
2  index=3  name=unknown   ngram=02   field=body   slop=0
```

I want to remove the extra field names on all data points in the data frame.
The result should be:

```
   index          name      ngram        field     slop  
0  1            unknown       00          body      0   
1  2            unknown       01          body      0   
2  3            unknown       02          body      0
```

I can remove the extra field name by iterating through every data point of the data frame:

```
for r in range(df.shape[0]):
    for c in range(df.shape[1]):
        df.iloc[r][c]=df.iloc[r][c].split('=')[1]
```

This is very slow and its not pythonic.

How can I remove the extra field names with high performance?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`pd.DataFrame.apply`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html):

```
df = df.apply(lambda x: x.str.split('=').str[-1])

print(df)

  index     name ngram field slop
0     1  unknown    00  body    0
1     2  unknown    01  body    0
2     3  unknown    02  body    0
```

This isn't vectorisable as you are working with `object` dtype series. You will likely want to convert certain series to numeric, e.g.

```
df['index'] = pd.to_numeric(df['index'])
```

---

For performance, a single `str` call is possible by calculating first the length of each column name:

```
d = dict(zip(df, df.columns.map(len)))
df = df.apply(lambda x: x.str[d[x.name]+1:])
```

Comment: The str.method() calls are vectorized, right? x. str.replace(x.name, "") is also an option for the lambda function. Might be slower though.

Comment: @FrancioRodrigues, No, `str` methods are **not** vectorised, they are for convenience only. Only numeric series (e.g. `int`, `float`, `bool`, `datetime`, even `category`) support vectorised operations.

Comment: I see. I had a misconception about the str methods. Thanks for clearing that up.

Answer (score 1):

Removal of characters from a string:

```
data['index'] = data['index'].map(lambda x: x.lstrip('index='))
```

untested iteration example:

```
for column in data:        
    data[column] = data[column].map(lambda x: x.lstrip(column + '='))
```

Comment: yes - you could use the column names as variables and iterate too

Answer (score 1):

Use [`str.replace`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.replace.html) :

```
df = df.replace(r'\w+\=(\w+$)', r'\1',regex=True)

print (df)

    index   name    ngram   field   slop
0    1    unknown    00      body    0
1    2    unknown    01      body    0
2    3    unknown    02      body    0
```

Answer (score 0):

Because you know the length of characters you want to remove in each column as it's the name of the column with =, you can do a loop `for` on columns and select the end of the string with `str[len(col)+1:]`:

```
for col in df.columns:
   df[col] = df[col].str[len(col)+1:]
```